# DynamoDB - Error is ResourceNotFoundException but cast fails in Go

Tags: go, error-handling, amazon-dynamodb

I wrote some code to attempt to get a table description in Go, using the [AWS SDK V2 DynamoDB package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb):

```
// First, create a connection to our local DynamoDB
client := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)

// Next, attempt to get the table description associated with the table name
output, err := client.DescribeTable(ctx, &dynamodb.DescribeTableInput{
    TableName: table.TableName,
})

// Now, if we got an error then check if it was a resource-not-found exception. If
// it was then that means we should create the table; otherwise, it means that something
// isn't right so return it. If the description was nil, we'll also create the table
var create bool
if err != nil {
    if _, ok := err.(*types.ResourceNotFoundException); !ok {
        return err
    } else {
        create = true
    }
} else if output == nil {
    create = true
}
```

During testing, this code returned the following error:

> operation error DynamoDB: DescribeTable, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 4b0bcb2b-c833-459f-9db2-54841aa1bbd3, ResourceNotFoundException

The problem I'm having is that this is clearly a `ResourceNotFoundException` but the cast is not working. Is there something else I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Not a solution, but one thing that might help is to log the actual type of the error to find out what it is. You can get the type in string format using `fmt.Sprintf("%T", err)`.

Comment: @phonaputer Yes, that is a workaround. But there should be a way to handle this.

Comment: Once you have learned the actual type of the error from your debug log, you can do a type assertion for the correct type. Or alternatively, you can use `errors.As` from the standard library. My guess is that the reason this is not working is one of: A. it's not actually a resource not found error, B. the type is not a pointer, C. the type is wrapped in another error (go 1.13 errors style). The debug log will allow you to understand which of these is happening and create a solution.

Comment: @phonaputer I ended up using `As` as well but without connecting the dots regarding the logging suggestion you made. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. First, one of the issues I had was that I was importing `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sso/types` instead of `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types` so my cast would never have worked. That being said, making this change did not fix the issue.

After log-debugging, I discovered that the v2 SDK wraps the AWS errors in a `*smithy.OperationError` type. Therefore, direct-casting and `errors.Is` won't work.

What I did that actually worked here was to change my error checking code to this:

```
if temp := new(types.ResourceNotFoundException); !errors.As(err, &temp) {
    return err
} else {
    create = true
}
```

Comment: In this link: https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/handling-errors/, AWS explains how to handle SDK errors for Go v2.

Comment: @Danizz Thanks for this. I really wish I'd found this documentation a year ago.

Comment: @Danizz this should be the accepted answer